# Controller not calling model function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I m trying to call the function `get_owner($id)` to get the name of the user, but it keep saying that: A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: incident/detail_page_admin.php

Line Number: 54
```

**View:**

```
<p id ="detail_owner">Criador do Incidente: <?php echo $incident_own->name;?></p>
```

**Controller:**

```
$aux = $this->incident_model->count_incident($this->session->userdata('usuario_id'));
$avatar = $this->usuario_model->get_avatar($this->session->userdata('usuario_id'));
$incident_owner = $this->usuario_model->get_owner($id);
$this->load->view('template/cabecalho');
$b = $this->incident_model->get_incident_by_id($id);
$this->load->view('incident/detail_page_admin', array('incident_own' => $incident_owner, 'count_incident' => $aux, 'incident_show_by_id' => $b, 'avatar_array' => $avatar));
$this->load->view('template/rodape');
```

**Model:**

```
function get_owner ($id){
    $a = $this->db->query('select name from usuario where id = ?', array($id));
    return $a->result();
}
```

Comment: Did you load your model ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than return `$a->result()` in your model function you want to return `$a->row()` and then it should work.

```
function get_owner ($id){
    $a = $this->db->query('select name from usuario where id = ?', array($id));
    return $a->row();
}
```

However returning `$a->row()` will only return one row which is fine if you are only expecting one row.  However if you expecting multiple rows to be returned you can do

```
function get_owner ($id){
    $a = $this->db->query('select name from usuario where id = ?', array($id));
    return $a;
}
```

Then you want to loop through the result rows in your view like

```
<?php foreach ($incident_own->result() as $row)
{ ?>
    <p id ="detail_owner">Criador do Incidente: <?php echo $row->name;?></p>
<?php } ?>
```